# Simplify expression with abstract matrices

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra

After defining a commutator function

```
Commutator[X_, Y_] := X.Y - Y.X;
```

I would like to be able to simplify abstract matrix algebra expressions such as

```
Simplify[Commutator[A + B, Commutator[A + B, A - B]] - 
  Commutator[A - B, Commutator[A + B, A - B]]]
```

instead of just printing out

```
-(A - B).(-(A - B).(A + B) + (A + B).(A - B)) + (A + 
    B).(-(A - B).(A + B) + (A + B).(A - B)) + (-(A - B).(A + B) + (A +
        B).(A - B)).(A - 
    B) - (-(A - B).(A + B) + (A + B).(A - B)).(A + B)
```

Is there a way to do this without downloading a non-commutative algebra package?

Answer (score 5):

Try `TensorReduce`

```
$Assumptions = {A ∈ Matrices[{n, n}], B ∈ Matrices[{n, n}]};
expr = Commutator[A + B, Commutator[A + B, A - B]] - 
  Commutator[A - B, Commutator[A + B, A - B]];
TensorReduce[expr]
(* 
A.MatrixPower[A - B, 2] + 2 A.MatrixPower[B, 2] + 
 A.MatrixPower[A + B, 2] + B.MatrixPower[A - B, 2] - 
 B.MatrixPower[A + B, 2] + 6 MatrixPower[B, 2].A - 6 B.A.B - 
 2 MatrixPower[A, 3] *)
```

I don't know why `TensorExpand` is not expanding `MatrixPower`, but you can distribute all the dot products first with:

```
distributeDot[expr_] := FixedPoint[MapAll[Distribute[#, Plus, Dot] &, #] &, expr]
```

After this it simplifies much further:

```
TensorReduce[distributeDot[expr]]
(* 4 A.MatrixPower[B, 2] + 4 MatrixPower[B, 2].A - 8 B.A.B *)
```